# Method of moments for the Logarithmic/Log-Series distribution

Tags: distributions, logarithm, method-of-moments

I'm looking for some more insights in applying the method of moments for the Logaritmic (or also called Log-Series) distribution.

The Logarithmic distribution only has one distribution parameter $0 < \alpha < 1$ and the mean is defined as:

$$E(X) = -\frac{\alpha}{(1-\alpha)\ln(1-\alpha)}.\tag{1}$$

We don't need the second moment necessarily, but interesting to see that the second moment is defined as:

$$E(X^2) = Var(X)+(E(X))^2 = -\frac{\alpha}{(1-\alpha)^2\ln(1-\alpha)},$$

where

$$Var(X) = -\frac{\alpha(\ln(1-\alpha)+\alpha)}{(1-\alpha)^2(\ln(1-\alpha))^2}.$$

However, I can't see how we could solve for $\alpha$ in $(1)$ or with the other information we have. There is also no literature I can find on applying the method of moments for the Logarithmic distribution.

Does anyone have an idea how to apply the method of moments for this distribution? Do we need to do it numerically?

Comment: Is "$\alpha$" the same as "$p$"?  Please explain what you mean by "solve for $\alpha.$" Do you mean, find $\alpha$ (*aka* $p$) based on the expectation?  If so, that's not an elementary function, but numerical solutions are efficient and easily implemented.

Comment: For $\alpha \in (0,1)$, you have $-\frac{\alpha}{(1-\alpha)\ln(1-\alpha)}$ is a continuous strictly increasing function of $\alpha$ onto $(1,\infty)$ and so you can invert this function to give an estimate of $\alpha$ for given $\bar X$.  I doubt there is a closed form, but numerical methods are likely to be fast

Comment: @whuber yes, $p = \alpha$, corrected. And yes, i was looking for an analytical solution to $\alpha$ based on the expectation. What do you mean with "an elementary function" ?

Comment: Numerical methods will work, while Wolfram Alpha suggests a solution using the [Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) (ProductLog): for example with $\bar X =3$ [it suggests](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=solve+3*%28%281-x%29*log%281-x%29%29%2Bx%3D0+) $\hat \alpha \approx 0.851$ and so more generally $\hat \alpha  = 1 - \exp(W_{-1}(-1/(\bar X \exp(1/\bar X))) + 1/\bar X)$

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method of moments would have us equate sample mean and population mean to solve for an estimate of this parameter.

Let's consider a concrete example, say $\bar{x}=2.3$. Then $-\frac{\hat{\alpha}}{(1-\hat{\alpha})\ln(1-\hat{\alpha)}}=2.3$. We can solve this by a variety of means -- binary search, [regula falsi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regula_falsi) (in one of its modern versions), or if you're writing code for others to use, perhaps something more sophisticated like Brent's method (or one of the more recent variants of it). If you have R, Brent's method can be performed by calling `uniroot` in R.

[image: Expectation as a function of the parameter with horizontal line at 2.3 meeting the curve and a vertical dropping from there to the x-axis just below 0.8]

But first, let's consider whether the function can be transformed to near linearity, which should speed up methods like regula falsi.

it turns out (with hardly any playing around) that if $g(x) = -\frac{x}{(1-x)\ln(1-x)}$ then $f(x)=1-g(x)^{-2}$ is much nearer to linear than $g$ itself

[image: transformed version of the mean as function of the parameter]

The red line is the $y=x$ line. We see that $1-1/2.3^2$ (marked horizontal line just above 0.8) is a little high, it hits the black curve somewhat to the left of 0.8.

That is, solving $f(\hat{\alpha})=1-1/g(\hat{\alpha})^2 = 1-1/2.3^2$ would be "nicer" numerically than solving the original equation; you can even do it to a couple of figures graphically.

So starting with $\hat{\alpha}^{[0]}=1-1/2.3^2 \approx 0.8$ would be a decent place to start, and iterating on that transformed function would be faster, if you're implementing an algorithm like regula falsi yourself.

Indeed, the transformed curve lies between the $y=x$ line (in red on the diagram above) and the line $y=1.048638 x$, offering pretty narrow bounds on the interval. Specifically, if $a_0 = 1-1/\bar{x}^2$, then $(a_0/1.048638,a_0)$ will bound the root. With $\bar{x}=2.3$ we'd start with the interval $(0.773349,0.810965)$ (rounding the first down and the second up).

Of course if you have a tool like Brent's method to hand, it's probably sufficient for your needs even without the transformation:

```
 f = function(a) -a/(1-a)/log(1-a) - 2.3

 uniroot(f,c(0.001,.999))
$root
[1] 0.7735663

$f.root
[1] 7.183583e-05

$iter
[1] 7

$init.it
[1] NA

$estim.prec
[1] 6.103516e-05
```

so for $\bar{x}=2.3$, the solution is approximately $\hat{\alpha}=0.7736$.

(If you're just doing this by hand a single time, something like binary search would suffice. Even trial and error on a calculator would get you there in a few minutes at most.)

Comment: `library(pracma); 1-exp(lambertWn(-1/(2.3*exp(1/2.3)))+1/2.3)` gives `0.7735549` in R

Comment: Thanks ... that agrees (to all figures) with what I found when I did it "by hand" rather than the call to uniroot.